# Blu-Ray drive seems to be recognized as harddrive (/dev/sdb) (drive conntected at SATA -> USB adapter)

Tags: usb, external-hdd, adapter, blu-ray, optical

I have connected my Blu-Ray disk drive via a SATA -> USB adapter to my notebook. But is not found as optical disk drive by the system.
When I type in

`lsusb`

it shows:

`Bus 004 Device 005: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge`

And when I do:
`dmesg | grep usb`

I get this:

```
[  550.307970] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  550.329197] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  550.329204] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  550.329208] usb 4-1: Product: USB3.0 External HDD
[  550.329211] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  550.329214] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0000AB123471
[  550.377597] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  550.383423] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  767.789350] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1639.778408] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1639.801798] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0888, bcdDevice= 0.36
[ 1639.801806] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1639.801810] usb 4-1: Product: Generic USB3.0 to SATA bridge
[ 1639.801814] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1639.801816] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 100000000000
[ 1639.804224] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1639.805605] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[ 2695.319025] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2695.350579] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0888, bcdDevice= 0.36
[ 2695.350586] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2695.350590] usb 1-1.2: Product: Generic USB3.0 to SATA bridge
[ 2695.350593] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2695.350596] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 100000000000
[ 2695.351614] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2695.353679] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 3194.899521] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 3202.289929] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 3202.312999] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0888, bcdDevice= 0.36
[ 3202.313006] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3202.313010] usb 4-1: Product: Generic USB3.0 to SATA bridge
[ 3202.313013] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 3202.313016] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 100000000000
[ 3202.315132] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3202.318204] scsi host8: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[29782.994567] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[29793.314714] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[29953.196427] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[29992.498565] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[29992.527741] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.12
[29992.527748] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[29992.527752] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 14020850010152
[29992.529173] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29992.529624] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[35677.229008] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[35989.549392] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[35989.570600] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 1.00
[35989.570607] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[35989.570611] usb 4-2: Product: USB3.0 External HDD
[35989.570614] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[35989.570617] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 0000AB123471
```

As far as I can see it is recognized as a hard disk drive. Is there a way on linux to change this or is it because of the adapter/ bridge and can not be changed? (In the last case I would of course purchase a new one. Anything I have to pay attention on?)

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it was because of the adapter/ bridge and therefore could not be changed. I had the same problem on other systems.